# Steam fails to download the missing ._.DS_Store file for Monaco

Tags: steam, macos, monaco

The other day I was trying to download Monaco, which I wanted to play with some friends.
However it would result in an unusual error, the likes of which I could not find on the internet (Or I missed it, but I did try).

What happens is as follows:
 1. I try to download the game.
 2. Steam downloads the game. 
 3. Steam then proceeds to show the following error:

[image: Missing downloaded files, in MONACO.app/Contents/Resources/Images/._.DS_Store]

What really baffles me is that a non-essential file, a `._.DS_Store`, is causing this trouble.

Does anyone know about a fix of some sort? 
I did try switching regions but to no avail.

Comment: At a guess macOS is merging the `._` file information in to the associated file and removing the file (like the `dot_clean` command) but the Steam downloader doesn't understand that this will happen. Not sure how you could work around that.

Comment: The file should be called `.DS_Store`. I've never seen a `._.DS_Store`. This is likely a bug. You should contact Steam Support and ask them what can be done. Worst case, you can ask a refund since you can't even play the game.

Comment: @Nolonar Files starting with '._' are used by macOS to store extended attributes for files on file systems that don't support extended attributes (FAT32 for example). So `._.DS_Store` is the extended attributes for the `.DS_Store` file.